# Is there a name for this variant on "continuous function"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote topological spaces. Then a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be *continuous* iff for all $U \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$, it holds that **if** $U$ is open in $Y$, **then** $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Suppose we change the implication to an equivalence. So the condition becomes becomes: for all $U \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$, it holds that $U$ is open in $Y$ **iff** $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Is there a name for such things?

Comment: Can every set in $X$ be described as $f^{-1}(U)$ for some $U \subseteq Y$?  Yes, since $f$ is a function and hence defined everywhere.  But $f$ is not necessarily bijective, and so an inverse function does not necessarily exist.  If an inverse function did exist, then we could say that your condition means $f^{-1}$ is also a continuous function.  And a bijective function $f$ that is continuous and has continuous inverse is called a *homeomorphism*.

Comment: @user46944, its not necessarily the case that every subset of $X$ can be described as $f^{-1}(U)$ for some $U \subseteq Y$, since we have not assumed that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: Take a constant function on any set with more than one point.

Comment: @user161825 Ah, I see, then the preimage of any subset of $Y$ is either the entire domain or $\emptyset$, depending on  whether or not the constant value the function attains is in our subset of $Y$.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, given a set $X$, a topological space $Y$, and a set function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, we can always define a topology on $X$ by saying that $U \in \mathcal P(X)$ is open in $X$ if and only if $U = f^{-1}(V)$ for some $V$ open in $Y$. Simply check that these sets satisfy the axioms for a topology.

So, changing "if" to "iff" in the definition of continuity, you are saying that $X$ has the unique [weakest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies) possible topology so that $f: X \rightarrow  Y$ is continous. That is, this topology on $X$ has the fewest possible open sets so that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function.

I'm not sure that if this is what you are looking for in terms of terminology. This is also implies that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ induces a [quotient map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) of $X$ onto $f(X) \subset Y$ with the subspace topology. If $f$ is surjective, then this definition is equivalent to the fact that $f$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Nice answer, though I somehow get the feeling that $P(Y)$ denotes the topology on $Y$ and not the power set.

Comment: @goblin, your definition was fine, my reading skills were not. It's a good question, and I hope my edited answer is more helpful.

Comment: @MorganO, its cool. For the record, the definition I wrote in the question was not the one I was trying to write! But its no big deal.

Comment: Are you sure about the last statement, that the condition given in the question is equivalent to saying that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ induces a quotient map of $X$ onto $f(X)$? I feel like this is a weaker condition than the one in the question.

Comment: For example, if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ has the property given in the question, then $Y \setminus f(X)$ with the subspace topology automatically has the discrete topology.

Comment: Recall that a map $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a quotient map if it is surjective, continuous, and $f^{-1}(U) \subset B$ open $\implies U \subset A$ open. 

The statement that $U \subset Y$ is open iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ is equivalent to the statement that then $U \cap f(X)$ is open in $f(X)$ with the subspace topology iff $f^{-1}(U \cap f(X))$ is open in $X$. The key is that we are considering $f(X)$ with the subspace topology. Does this help?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. By the *image* of a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$, I mean $f(X)$. Now consider the inclusion $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This is a quotient map onto its image. However, its not the case that we can conclude that $[5,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ just by observing that its preimage under $f$ is open in $[0,1]$. So despite that $f$ has the property that it is a quotient map onto its image, nonetheless it does not satisfy the property described in the question.

Comment: Which is exactly what tripped me up in formulating the darn thing. What I really want to know is, what do we call a function between topological spaces that is a quotient mapping onto its image?

Comment: @goblin you're correct, I was sloppy in claiming equivalence. The implication only goes one way (see my edit). I'm not sure about this word-- perhaps simply a "quotient map onto its image"?